# selecting element from a html string inside variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html string data inside variable like this

```
 var htmlstring = "<div><div class='testdiv'>924422</div></div>"
```

What I am expecting is to fetch content of div having class.In this example .testdiv data.

**How can I achieve?.**

*I know one approach: Append this html string to html page and then access.But I dont want to do it as I am using ajax and server returning kind of html string.Now I want to fetch data inside specific div.*

So is there any alternative way to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you don't use `.` in class name in html. And to fetch the content of that div in html string, you could use jquery `find` function.

```js
var htmlstring = "<div><div class='testdiv'>924422</div></div>"
alert($(htmlstring).find('.testdiv').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you can achieve it without jQuery.

```js
var htmlstring = "<div><div class='testdiv'>924422</div></div>";

function getTestDiv(htmlString) {
  var textVal = null;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString;
  var elements = div.childNodes;
  if (elements.item(0).childNodes.item(0).className === 'testdiv') {
    textVal = elements.item(0).childNodes.item(0).innerHTML;
  }
  return textVal;
}

console.log(getTestDiv(htmlstring));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by :

```
console.log($(htmlstring).find("div.testdiv").text());
```

Comment: String has no method `find()`

Comment: Yup, just forgot the `$` sign